# Merge variables and set old variable name as new variable

Tags: r, dataframe, pivot

My data set looks like this:

| variable1 | variable2 | variable3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| value1 | NA | NA |
| NA | value2 | NA |
| NA | NA | value3 |

I want to transform it into this:

| variable | value |
| --- | --- |
| variable1 | value1 |
| variable2 | value2 |
| variable3 | value3 |

Is there any function I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `tidyr::pivot_longer` with `values_drop_na = TRUE`:

```r
library(tidyr)
pivot_longer(df, everything(), names_to = "variable", values_drop_na = TRUE)
```

```r
  variable  value 
  <chr>     <chr> 
1 variable1 value1
2 variable2 value2
3 variable3 value3
```

Comment: Wow, that was fast. And it works. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Another option using `gather` from `tidyr` with `na.rm = TRUE`:

```r
df <- read.table(text = "variable1  variable2   variable3
value1  NA  NA
NA  value2  NA
NA  NA  value3
", header = TRUE)

library(tidyr)
gather(df, key = "variable", value = "value", na.rm = TRUE)
#>    variable  value
#> 1 variable1 value1
#> 5 variable2 value2
#> 9 variable3 value3
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-31 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

In `base R`, we can use `stack`

```
na.omit(stack(df1)[2:1])
        ind values
1 variable1 value1
5 variable2 value2
9 variable3 value3
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(variable1 = c("value1", NA, NA), variable2 = c(NA, 
"value2", NA), variable3 = c(NA, NA, "value3")),
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```